# Does pending transactions use the current variable on the blockchain?

Tags: solidity, transactions

Say I have a public variable called:

```
uint256 testInt;
```

1. When I call a function that reads from testInt and then modifies testInt, it will be pending.
2. Now I submit a new transaction with a higher gas price. It calls the same function. This transaction will process before the pending function.

My question is that will the testInt that is read in 1. be the one modified by 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions happen in a defined order. If transaction #2 runs before transaction #1, then transaction #1 will see the value as it is after transaction #2.